# What are Bridges and Relay Centers in Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, relays, configuration, bridge

While configuring Tor you get something called Bridges and Relay Center.
I have tried to decode what is this exactly and how to configure this but failed miserably due to which I just removed the complete software(Vidalia Relay center etc.)

Sometimes I could set up a bridge but after setting the bridge we even have a public or a private bridge. Things like enter/exit relay . For which it again made it complex.

Even the Tor application for Android is also some what difficult (You every time need to enable Tor check for existing connections and then use the internet).

Could anyone provide a step by step screen shot regarding the configuration of Tor on Windows as well as Android Jellybean (4.1.2).

Comment: It is not clear what your question is? Do you have a problem using Tor? Or do you complain about complexity of Tor? Please clearly ask your question so that folks comprehend your question.

Comment: @Roya Off course the complexity regarding the setup and usage of TOR

Comment: Dear, it is Tor not TOR.

Comment: Ya okay The onion Router now could we please concentrate on the prob here

Comment: @Roya happy dear

Comment: Is this question that tough for no one seems to answer

Comment: Dear, be patient. Today is 4th of July. This is a public holiday in U.S.

Comment: Didn't mean to be rude but couldn't help with the config

Comment: @Roya Dear, its been almost two weeks and still there's no answer from any side are some  still celebrating the public holiday :-)

Comment: Dear, Do you want to use Tor as client only or you want to run a relay?

Comment: As a client is very easy for simple bypassing but I want to use it in a advanced way initially, if successful then I would also set a relay for helping others

Comment: pehaps adding a screenshot(s)/video of the interface will clarify your question?